# Git: Same feature on multiple branches, but not on master

Tags: git

Our supplier has provided the code to run the linux kernel on their hardware, however there are 2 kernel versions - one that they use for Android (kernel 2.6), another for Yocto (kernel 3.01).
Now I've done some modifications to the hardware and added a few drivers to support the new hardware in kernel 2.6, as shown with X and Y, but I want to apply the same change to 3.01.

Now:

```
   E -- F -- G -- X -- Y (2.6)
 /
A -- B -- C -- D (master)
      \
       H -- I -- J (3.01)
```

After:

```
   E -- F -- G -- X -- Y (2.6)
 /
A -- B -- C -- D (master)
      \
       H -- I -- J -- X -- Y (3.01)
```

What would be the best way to go about it? I've read about cherry picking and that it isn't a good practice.
I would like to avoid touching the master at all since my hardware is completely irrelevant to the mainline kernel development.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your commit diagram is impossible. You cannot have two different `X` and `Y` commits with different ancestors. Git *cannot* do that, there is no solution that can produce that commit graph.

The answer is (good practice or not) cherry picking, and a commit graph that looks like this:

```
   E -- F -- G -- X -- Y (2.6)
 /
A -- B -- C -- D (master)
     \
      H -- I -- J -- X' -- Y' (3.01)
```

Where `X'` and `Y'` are the cherry-picked versions of `X` and a`Y`.

Whatever made you think it isn't a "good practice" is irrelevant; it's the only way to arrive at the results you're after.

Comment: Ok, thanks!
So as I understand, as I develop the feature on one branch, I will just have to remember to always cherry pick all my commits for the other branch as well.

Comment: The real problem is that you have such divergent histories with new feature work happening on both branches. If both branches are under active development, you should merge them back together. If you have a legacy branch, you shouldn't be back-porting new features to it, only bug fixes, which is what cherry-picking is really meant to facilitate.

Comment: I agree, but in this case there really isn't a choice - Android needs the 2.6 kernel and Yocto needs the 3.01 kernel, but before I even get to that the SoC manufacturer applies hundreds of patches to each branch separately. But thanks for your help! It helps to know that whatever I've been told isn't good is actually the only choice.